# Security propagation between web and ejb modules in EAR

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee, ejb, jaas

My app has a form security domain and security decisions are programmatic and fine grained. This works well for the Servlets. But i also invoke EJB methods that return models based on whether user that requests the model is in a particular role, just like HttpServletRequest::isUserInRole("someRole") is used to make a decision whether return some resource or not, but on a finer level.

That doesn't seem to work - security is not propagated:

```
@Resource SessionContext ctx; //in a session bean
```

ctx's getUserPrincipal().getName() always returns "anonymous".

Search throughout the internet didn't net anything positive. I am thinking now of refactoring EJB's methods to accept HttpServletRequest reference, but this will be messy and hacky... just doesn't seem like a good practice.

Have anyone got any tips?